How can fix ftp server folder and file name error?
I have a simple ftp server written in C#. But I am having problems creating folder and file names. If the creation date of the folder or file is greater than 180 days, the folder or file name is created correctly.
Example:
sample img
In this screenshot values like (Tem 07 2023) should not be in the folder name. This values are should be in last write time column.
Here is my code
IEnumerable<string> directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(pathname);

foreach (string dir in directories)
{
    DateTime editDate = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dir);

    string date = editDate < now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(180)) ?
    editDate.ToString("MMM dd  yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) :
    editDate.ToString("MMM dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    dataWriter.Write("drwxr-xr-x    2 2003     2003         4096 ");
    dataWriter.Write(date);
    dataWriter.Write(' ');
    dataWriter.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(dir));

    dataWriter.Flush();
}

I fix the problem here is the solution, if i write date parameter with this format there is no date in the folder name.
 dataWriter.Write($"{date,12:MMM dd HH:mm}");


if you want to create a folder with same name - remove /comment this line dataWriter.Write(date);

that code is for folder's lastwrite time property. I'm passing that value to lastwrite time column not folder name column so it shouldnt be in folder name. I want to pass last write time as property and it should not be in the folder name. It is unix format.   Every value in that string has different property. Check below. permissions[tab]inode[tab]owner[tab]group[tab]filesize[tab]date[tab]filename

You can show respect for those who might help you by properly formatting your code sample so it's not indented way to the right.

Also, you can save a bunch of disk I/O by using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories() instead of Directory.EnumerateDirectories(), which will give you the LastWriteTime property as part of the initial read.
